# Play music when I select UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaitem

I can show music library on UITableView.

```
  songsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
MPMediaQuery *playlistQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc]init];
[playlistQuery setGroupingType:MPMediaGroupingTitle];
songArray = [playlistQuery items];
for (MPMediaItem *song in songArray) {
    NSString *songTitle = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];        
    [songsArray addObject:songTitle];
}
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:                (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.textLabel.text = [songsArray objectAtIndex:row];
[cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

But I can't play music when I selected `UITableView` Cell.

```
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;

NSString *selectedSong = [songsArray objectAtIndex:row];
MPMusicPlayerController *appPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];

[appPlayer setQueueWithQuery:selectedSong];

[appPlayer play];

}
```

Comment: Does the MPMusiePlayerController work without the tableView, if you manually select a song?

Comment: Yes, I select a song without MediaPicker.

Comment: I'll pick a song like iPhone's default music player(iPod)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I see the problem:

Move this code:

```
NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
NSString *selectedSong = [songsArray objectAtIndex:row];
MPMusicPlayerController *appPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
[appPlayer setQueueWithQuery:selectedSong];
[appPlayer play];
```

to the UITableViewDelegate protocol method 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
    NSString *selectedSong = [songsArray objectAtIndex:row];
    MPMusicPlayerController *appPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
    [appPlayer setQueueWithQuery:selectedSong];
    [appPlayer play];
}
```

**Edit**

Documentation:

- [UITableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [UITableViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate)
- [UITableViewDataSource Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource)
- [MPMusicPlayerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)
- [MPMediaQuery Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaQuery_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MPMediaQuery)
- [Using the iPod Library / iPod Library Access Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/UsingTheiPodLibrary/UsingTheiPodLibrary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH101-SW1)

Comment: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct NSString *', expected 'struct MPMediaQuery *' when passing argument 1 of 'setQueueWithQuery:' from distinct Objective-C type. What's wrong?

Comment: The setQueueWithQuery expects a MPMediaQuery object. Please refer to Apple's documentation.

Comment: But I can't find any documents about UITableView.

Comment: I've added some documentation links which could be helpful for you.